# How to call SoundPlayer type variables in different methods

Tags: c#, reference, static, public

So I'm making a sort of music player that at the moment has 8 different music genres to choose from and I'm having problems with using the .play() and .stop() funcionalities that System.Media.SoundPlayer provides outside the method in which the SoundPlayer variables are created.

I've tried making the variables public but that doesn't seem to be possible. I have the SoundPlayer variables declared like so:

```cs
Stream rockmusic = Properties.Resources.rock1;
SoundPlayer playrock = new SoundPlayer(rockmusic);
```

I wanted to make it so that i could use playrock.Play(); and playrock.Stop(); inside a different method like

```cs
private void ButtonWTVClick(object sender, EventArgs e){

playrock.Play();

}
```

But public static doesnt work  for either System.IO.Stream nor System.Media.SoundPlayer so I'm a bit stuck on how to implement those funcionalities into different methods since I'm fairly new to programming and dont know all the possibilities.

Comment: To make a member public you need to declare it public, like in `public SoundPlayer playrock ...`, if that is what you want to know.

Comment: i cant use public on SoundPlayer or it will say that the streams i declared before don't exist in the current context ex:```cs 
public Stream rockmusic = Properties.Resources.rock1;
SoundPlayer playrock = new SoundPlayer(rockmusic); //"the name 'rockmusic' doesn't exist in the current context"
```

Comment: You could initialize the `playrock` directly with `new SoundPlayer(Properties.Resources.rock1)` and expose `playrock.Stream` through a property `rockmusic` (if you really need that as a member). Or move the initialization to the constructor. Maybe share more context with us to make it clearer what you're after here.

Comment: Thanks sticky that worked and it was pretty simple to implement, Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use sticky bit's last suggestion, and declare it at Class/Form level, like this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    private SoundPlayer playrock = new SoundPlayer(Properties.Resources.rock1);

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void ButtonWTVClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        playrock.Play();
    }

}
```